# JQuery trigger keydown while pressing another key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to press the numpad `6` and that triggers pressing the `comma` key.

I've attempted but doesn't work.

```
<input name="text" value="" />
<script type="javascript/text">
    $(function() {
        $("input").keypress(function (e) {

            if (e.which == 102) { //numpad 6

            e = jQuery.Event("keydown"); // define this once in global scope
            e.which = 188; // Comma
            $(this).trigger(e);

            }
      });

    });
</script>
```

How do i solve?  The outcome i want is pressing the numpad `6`, instead of a 6 appearing in the input a `comma` appears.

Comment: Maybe you should `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Your requirements make very little sense - you want pressing a `6` to show a `,` in an input...?

Comment: Yes, my client is using a plugin that changes the language in the input textfield.   They want the numpad 6 to be a comma.  Because the comma key is used by the plugin.

Comment: Try preventDefault as stated above and return false on the first event?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do smt like this

```
$(function() {
    $("input").keypress(function (e) {

        if (e.which == 102) { 
             e.preventDefault();
             $(this).val(e.currentTarget.value + ',')

        }
  });
});
```